# Browserify bundle.js file large even without map

Tags: backbone.js, browserify

I have a node_modules folder with different packages that are used for Gulp and there are also jQuery and Backbone.js packages which are used in the project. Backbone.js and jQuery, if minified, make a total of around 100 kb. I have also a few small js files. But the bundle.js for the build (minified) is almost 400 kb. I checked if there were any dependencies, like underscore, loaded multiple times and everything was loaded only once. 
I can't figure out why the build size is 4 times as big as it should be.

Comment: Are you running the generate bundle through a minifier? Browserfiy doesn't minify for you, it just concatenates.

Comment: You gave me a hint : -) There was a bug in gulp settings. Now bundle is minified. Thanks!